# The end of this journey

Tags: riddle

A great wise man once said that
although it is only a foot or two away,
this journey can take you many years.
The end of this journey is what you seek, 
whether you know it or not.

hint:

> No matter you are young or old, the mind can be cold.

To answer this question, there are two parts:

What is this destination?
Where are you traveling from?

Note:

This is a true story.

Comment: Who is this "great wise man" and when did this "true story" happened?

Comment: About the "true story" , it was said by Srinivas Arka, whom I know very well.  He wrote a book called Adventures in Self Discovery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is this destination?

> Heart

Where are you traveling from?

> Mind

A great wise man once said that
although it is only a foot or two away,

> This is roughly a distance between your head and your heart.

this journey can take you many years.

> We try to overcome illusions of our *mind* and find who we really are deeply in our *heart*.

The end of this journey is what you seek, whether you know it or not.

> Your mind may not *know* what you seek, but it's your heart that *feels* seeking. So whether we know it or not, we seek to find who we are and what is that we really seek.

Comment: Bravo +1 .. Congrats on receiving the bounty. Excellent answer.  Also, congratulations on this being your first accepted answer on this site!

Comment: What is this destination?

Heart   , thats weard

Comment: @MichaelRize But he hasn't received the bounty yet! Also, nice riddle :-)

Answer (score 14):

What is this destination?

> Adulthood

Where are you traveling from?

> Adolescence

A great wise man once said that
although it is only a foot or two away,

> Most people will grow a foot, or two, from adolescence to adulthood

this journey can take you many years.

> Yes, it will

The end of this journey is what you seek, whether you know it or not.

> No child wants to stay a child forever

Comment: I had not considered this solution, good job.  However, not all of us are adolescent now, so it does not meet all criteria.  The correct answer applies to all people, young or old.  "The end of this journey is what you seek."

Comment: Fair enough, my take on it was that there was nothing to say people might have already taken the journey. So yes, not everyone is adolescent right now but they were and they took that journey. Back to the drawing board for me!

Answer (score 9):

The destination is:

> Death

You are travelling to there from:

> Life

Why?

```
although it is only a foot or two away,
```

> You are buried at that depth

```
this journey can take you many years.
```

> It takes pretty much your whole life

```
The end of this journey is what you seek, whether you know it or not.
```

> We are all headed there, whether we realize it or not.

Comment: I do believe people are buried deeper than that, otherwise nice try. Also, most people do not seek death.

Comment: This is exactly what I would have said! +1

Comment: "6 feet under" is the correct measurement.

Answer (score 0):

I call upon the lessons my father has taught me when I answer this:

> The first step. It has been said that the first step toward any goal is always the most difficult one, in that it means beginning your journey requires motivation that you may need to accumulate over the years. The distance in the idiom is measured as a foot or two because that's the accepted length of a human stride. Sometimes, the end of your journey is not what you expected when you started. It's difficult to spell out a specific *to* and *from*, but I suppose the best summary would be
>  **To: The first step towards a goal
>
>  From: Figuratively standing in place, unmotivated**

Comment: I like this answer.  However, "The end of this journey is what you seek".   The first step is the journey, not the destination.

Answer (score 0):

What is this destination?

> Marriage

Where are you traveling from?

> Being single / alone

A great wise man once said that
although it is only a foot or two away,

> The person you feel an affection for can be right in front of you

this journey can take you many years.

> Getting to know someone, figuring out compatibility, building a large degree of intimacy, and allowing for life plans can all make getting to marriage take a long time

The end of this journey is what you seek, whether you know it or not.

> The end of the journey would be the wedding, finally reaching the goal you set out for. You may be seeking it as a way to "cement" your relationship in place

Comment: Very clever, but again does not meet all criteria as not everyone is single.

Answer (score 0):

What is this destination?

> Knowledge

Where are you traveling from?

> Ignorance

...although it is only a foot or two away,

> A comfortable distance for books (well, maybe now a tablet or Kindle)

...this journey can take you many years.

> Learning can take a lifetime

...The end of this journey is what you seek, whether you know it or not.

> Wisdom / Enlightenment

Answer (score -1):

What is this destination?

> Truth.

Where are you traveling from?

> Illusion.